# How to hide java window when using StanfordNERTagger

Tags: java, python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am using StanfordNERTagger with NLTK wrapper for Python as described in this example: (https://pythonprogramming.net/named-entity-recognition-stanford-ner-tagger/)

When the line:

```
classified_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)
```

from example above is executed, this window opens:

[image]

Is there a way to hide it?

Comment: Nope. Don't think that it's possible for Windows.

Comment: BTW the Stanford API you're using in NLTK is outdated.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any advice on what to use? I have been using spaCy also.

Comment: "Get Linux/Mac" might be the best thing to do machine learning and NLP =)